# How to disable USB data connectivity on rooted device

Tags: usb, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I have a Transformer TF101 and I have Android 4.0. I want to disable the USB data connectivity of it for my purposes. The device is rooted.

How can I do that, and can I change the implementation of the USB driver ?

Comment: I tweaked your question to be more about a problem to be solved rather than asking how to implement a solution you've already identified.